# Move the cookies from the browser

Tags: browser, cookies

How it is possible to move cookie from one browser to another? This must be done through the browser options

Comment: Why -3, I simply asked a question?

Comment: I am doing a project that uses cookies, and my boss asks me what will happen if I copy the cookie from another browser and put it in your own?

Comment: In that case, my answer is not relevant to your question. It sounds like your boss is talking about some kind of cookie/session hijacking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cookie_hijacking / http://codebutler.com/firesheep You have -3 because it's **Really Hard** to tell what you're asking.

Comment: I translate his words through Google Translate.

Comment: It's not about the words you use. It's about the context surrounding the question. Can you give us any more details about what you/your bosh ultimately wish to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would like to be able to set a cookie in one browser (such as Google Chrome) and be able to access it from another browser (such as IE6).

If that is the case, check out [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) (a very beefy solution).

If you want something more lightweight, you could try [Adobe Flash cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object).

An easy way to see flash cookies in action:

- In one browser open a YouTube video.
- Change the volume.
- Open a YouTube video in another browser.
- You will be able to see that the volume has been remembered between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to manually copy cookies between browsers, [this JavaScript bookmarklet](http://yaisb.blogspot.com/2006/05/cookie-hacking-bookmarklet.html) may be useful - it allows you to access and modify the cookies of the current domain; this means you could run it in one browser, copy the cookies to clipboard, then run in another browser and paste.

Note that some apps may store browser-specific data (or flags) in cookies (or related components, like sessions), which may lead to strange behavior (e.g. "this-cookie-was-set-for-IE6=1, enable broken-browser-workarounds").